# C2672 "std::_Variant_raw_get": не найдена соответствующая перегруженная функция

Tags: c++

```
typedef std::variant<bool, LED::colour, LED::RateType, nullptr_t> ParamContainer;    
std::get<std::string>(this->get_param());
```

Ошибка  C2672   "std::_Variant_raw_get": не найдена соответствующая перегруженная функция

Самое странное, что этот же код компилируется нормально на Coliru. Кто-нибудь знает, почему я не смог собрать решение в Visual Studio в виду этой ошибки?

```
class Command // to execute it by manually calling LED functions (e.g. turning it off)
{
public:
    typedef std::variant<bool, LED::colour, LED::RateType, nullptr_t> ParamContainer;

    Command(const ParamContainer& c = nullptr) : // no arg by default
        has_res(false),
        param(c)
    {
    }
    
    const ParamContainer& get_param() const
    {
        return this->param;
    }

    bool has_result() const
    {
        return this->has_res;
    }

    virtual bool apply(LED& l) = 0;
    virtual void get_result(LED& l, std::string& d) = 0;

protected:
    void set_flag(bool f)
    {
        this->has_res = f;
    }

private:
    bool has_res;
    ParamContainer param;
};

class GetState : public Command
{
public:
    GetState()
    {
        set_flag(true);
    }

    bool apply(LED&) override
    {
        // pass
        
        return true;
    }

    void get_result(LED& l, std::string& d) override
    {
        if (has_result())
        {
            utils::to_string_state(l, d);
        }
    }
};
class SetState : public Command
{
public:

    SetState(const ParamContainer& params) : Command(params)
    {
    }

    bool apply(LED& led) override
    {
        try
        {
            std::get<std::string>(this->get_param());
            std::string str;
            if (str == "on")
            { }
            bool v = true;
            led.set_state(v);
        }
        catch (std::bad_variant_access&) // no arg
        {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    void get_result(LED& l, std::string& d) override
    {
        // pass 
        // this command has no output
    }
};
```

Comment: В параметрах шаблона есть std::string?...

Comment: `std::get<std::string>( std::variant<> );` должна вернуть значение типа `string`, содержащееся в `std::variant<>`. А у вас в `std::variant<>` не содержится ни одного значения типа `string`.

Comment: @ARHovsepyan, спасибо!